# Excel VBA Iteration Copy and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that declares a range of cells and copies and pastes each cell 1 at a time  in to cell "A2". This should only happen if the cell in column have data present.

The error I'm getting is a Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

I'm more from a C# background so I'm hoping its just a syntax error but this is what I have so far.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Update1()
'
' Update1 Macro
' Update
'
  Dim PartListRange As Range
  Dim PartListCell As Range

  Set PartListRange = Sheets("Query").Range("C2:100")

  For Each PartListCell In PartListRange.Cells
     If Cell.Value <> "" Then
         Worksheets("Query").Range(PartListCell).Copy _
         Destination:=Worksheets("Query").Range("A2")
         ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
     End If
  Next PartListCell

End Sub
```

Comment: You are looking at Range C2:C100, If it's not empty, copy the data to the same sheet, Column A?

Comment: The problem with `Set PartListRange = Sheets("Query").Range("C2:100")1` is `C2:C100`

Comment: copy the data one at a time only in to cell "A2" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly different way of doing the same thing, using `.Cells(row,col)` and setting the values using a loop.

Using lastRow, instead of row 100.  You can change that if need be.  I'm including it, because most times that's needed.

**What this does:**

- Loop through the range of 2-100 or 2-lastRow, depending on your choice.
- Check the value in column "C" to make sure it isn't empty.
- If not empty, copy to Range("A2").  (note, each iteration that the conditions match will over-write)
- Pause in the action to run a macro or call another sub, using a MsgBox, in this example as a placeholder

**Code:**  Un-comment lines related to lastRow to utilize it.

```
Sub conditionalCopy()

'Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sName As String

    sName = "Query"
    'lastRow = Sheets(sName).Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    'For lRow = 2 to lastRow        'Uncomment lastRow to use instead of 100 for max.
    For lRow = 2 To 100             'Range("C2:C100")    
        If Sheets(sName).Cells(lRow, "C").Text <> "" Then
            Sheets(sName).Range("A2").Value = Sheets(sName).Cells(lRow, "C").Value
            MsgBox("Here is your break in the action..." & vbNewLine & _
                   "Press Enter to continue loop")
        End If
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I edit this so that each cell it copied, it was only pasted in to cell "A2"?

Comment: Do you mean A2 for every row?  You would only see the last one done.  Because they'd all rewrite it.  If you wanted to do that, you'd say `.Cells(2,"A")` instead of `(lRow, "A")`

Comment: Yeah that's what I want it do. Eventually I will call another macro after each iteration to gather data based on the data in Cell "A2".

Comment: Revised to pause with MsgBox

Comment: how do I change this line of code to work with columns and not rows??
lastRow = Sheets(sName).Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

Comment: `lastCol = Sheets(sName).Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column` Where 1 is the column header row.  It's best to use the headers, knowing that you have data in that row.  `Dim lastCol As Long`

Answer (score 0):

```
If Cel.Value <> "" Then
```

you spelt Cell wrong

```
ParListCell
```

and Part :P

Comment: This doesn't fix the error. Excel is saying the error is something to do with the line Set PartListRange = Sheets("Query").Range("C2:100")

Comment: Thank you for fixing my bad spelling ;-)